# Simple issue with as.numeric

Tags: r, matrix

I have this matrix:

```
Catergory  Reason          Species
[1,] "Decline"  "Genuine"       "24"   
[2,] "Improved" "Genuine"       "16"    
[3,] "Improved" "Misclassified" "24"   
[4,] "Decline"  "Misclassified" "16"   
[5,] "Decline"  "taxonomic"     "24"   
[6,] "Improved" "Taxonomic"     "16"   
[7,] "Decline"  "Unclear"       "24"   
[8,] "Improved" "Unclear"       "16"
```

I want to make the third column numeric so I try:

```
Reasonstats[,3]<-as.numeric(Reasonstats[,3])
```

It doesn't give me any errors, but the values remain not numerical. If I just do

```
as.numeric(Reasonstats[,3])
```

it gives me a list of them as numeric and if I do

```
Reasonstats[,3]<-2
```

it subs in 2 fine.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thank you

Comment: A `matrix` can only contain data of one type, so since you have strings in your matrix, everything will be stored as characters. Try `data.frame`s instead if you want different data types in each column.

Comment: @AnandaMahto you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To understand "what's going wrong", you need to start with reading the help page for `?matrix`, which would lead you to the help page for `?as.vector`. Reading `?as.vector`, you would find:

> `as.vector`, a generic, attempts to coerce its argument into a vector of mode `mode` (the default is to coerce to whichever vector mode is most convenient)

A few examples to understand this:

```
A <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
A
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
mode(A)
# [1] "logical"
B <- c(TRUE, TRUE, 0)
B
# [1] 1 1 0
as.logical(B)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
mode(B)
# [1] "numeric"
C <- c(TRUE, FALSE, "zero")
C
# [1] "TRUE"  "FALSE" "zero" 
mode(C)
# [1] "character"
```

So, understanding that `as.vector` cannot contain mixed atomic modes, we can conclude that a `matrix` (which is basically a `vector` with a `dim` attribute specifying the number of rows and columns) also cannot contain mixed atomic modes.

Reading about more storage structures in R, you will encounter the `data.frame`. The help page for `?data.frame` describes this as:

> ... a matrix-like structure whose columns may be of differing types (numeric, logical, factor and character and so on).

So, if you want a rectangular table like you have shown, but with columns of different types, you should use a `data.frame`, not a `matrix`.

Assuming your `matrix` to be "m", defined as:

```
m <- structure(
  c("Decline", "Improved", "Improved", "Decline", "Decline", 
    "Improved", "Decline", "Improved", "Genuine", "Genuine", 
    "Misclassified", "Misclassified", "taxonomic", "Taxonomic",
    "Unclear", "Unclear", "24", "16", "24", "16", "24", "16", 
    "24", "16"), 
  .Dim = c(8L, 3L), 
  .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Catergory", "Reason", "Species")))
```

First, convert it to a `data.frame`:

```
m2 <- data.frame(m, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Then convert your "Species" column to numeric:

```
m2$Species <- as.numeric(m2$Species)
```

Here's the result, and its structure.

```
m2
#   Catergory        Reason Species
# 1   Decline       Genuine      24
# 2  Improved       Genuine      16
# 3  Improved Misclassified      24
# 4   Decline Misclassified      16
# 5   Decline     taxonomic      24
# 6  Improved     Taxonomic      16
# 7   Decline       Unclear      24
# 8  Improved       Unclear      16
str(m2)
# 'data.frame':  8 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ Catergory: chr  "Decline" "Improved" "Improved" "Decline" ...
#  $ Reason   : chr  "Genuine" "Genuine" "Misclassified" "Misclassified" ...
#  $ Species  : num  24 16 24 16 24 16 24 16
```